# Using CodePipeline to Deploy ElasticBeanstalk application in another AWS account

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

We have a setup with different AWS accounts for each environment(`dev`, `test`, `prod`) and then a shared build account which has a `AWS CodePipeline` that deploys into each of these environment by assuming a role in `dev`, `test`, `prod`.

This works fine for our Serverless applications using a `Codebuild` script.

Can we do something similar for the `Elastic Beanstalk` application that uses the deploy action provider? Or what is the best approach for `Elastic Beanstalk`

Comment: I am also trying to do exactly same but using AWS CDK and I also raised ticket to paid AWS tech support and they responded as of now there is no deploy to elastic beanstalk code deploy action available. Although I had it working into the same aws account by implementing IAction interface -
https://github.com/dhirajkhodade/CDKDotNetWebAppEbPipeline/blob/b3512e6d172b3ea9f238a8a9b391710354ae3608/lib/cdk_dot_net_web_app_eb_pipeline-stack.ts#L89

This might help someone implement same for cross account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up solving it this way using `CodeBuild`:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      python: 3.8
    commands:
      - pip install awsebcli --upgrade
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - CRED=`aws sts assume-role --role-arn $assume_role --role-session-name codebuild-deployment-$environment`
      - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=`node -pe 'JSON.parse(process.argv[1]).Credentials.AccessKeyId' "$CRED"`
      - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=`node -pe 'JSON.parse(process.argv[1]).Credentials.SecretAccessKey' "$CRED"`
      - export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=`node -pe 'JSON.parse(process.argv[1]).Credentials.SessionToken' "$CRED"`
      - export AWS_EXPIRATION=`node -pe 'JSON.parse(process.argv[1]).Credentials.Expiration' "$CRED"`
      - echo $(aws sts get-caller-identity)
  build:
    commands:
      - eb --version
      - eb init <project-name> --platform "Node.js running on 64bit Amazon Linux" --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
      - eb deploy
```

Using the `aws-cli` to assume the role we needed and then using `eb-cli` to do the actual deployment. Not sure if this is the best way, but it works. We are considering moving to another CI/CD tool which is more flexi

Answer (score 0):

We do this by using a CodeBuild job specified in each of the *stage* accounts (`dev`, `test`, `prod`) that uses the AWS CLI to deploy the CodePipeline artifact (available as `CODEBUILD_SOURCE_VERSION` in your build job's environment variables) to Elastic Beanstalk. We run this job as part of a CodePipeline in our shared build account.

These are the AWS CLI commands the CodeBuild *deploy* job runs:

```
aws elasticbeanstalk create-application-version --application-name ... --version-label ... --source-bundle S3Bucket="codepipeline-artifacts-us-east-1-123456789012",S3Key="application/deployable/XXXXXXX"
aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --environment-name ... --version-label ...
```

You can specify a CodeBuild job from another account in CodePipeline using the strategy outlined here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/pipelines-create-cross-account.html. It involves setting up cross-account access to the `role_arn` used for the CodeBuild *deploy* job and a customer managed KMS key for the pipeline (with a cross-account access policy).

One deficiency with this approach is that the CodeBuild deploy job will complete as soon as the deployment starts and not wait until the ElasticBeanstalk deployment succeeds or fails, as the native CodePipeline EB deploy action does. You should be able to call `aws elasticbeanstalk describe-environments` in a loop from the job to replicate this behavior, but I have not yet attempted this. (Sample script here: https://blog.cyplo.net/posts/2018/04/wait-for-beanstalk/)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to cross account deployment of application to elastic beanstalk in another aws account using aws cdk.

As aws cdk do not have deploy to elastic beanstalk action feature yet so we have to implement it manually by implementing IAction interface

You can find complete working CDK app in my git repo

https://github.com/dhirajkhodade/CDKDotNetWebAppEbPipeline